# genymotion 2.0.3: add a restricted profile

Tags: android, user-management, genymotion, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm running a **Nexus 7** emulated device (**API 18**) using the **Genymotion 2.0.3** emulator. And I have the google APIs installed and signed into a google account.

How do I add a restricted user profile? There is no **Users** menu item in the settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable it via adb:

```
$ adb shell setprop fw.max_users 4
```

To make it work even after reboot you can do next:

```
$ adb remount
$ adb shell
# echo "fw.max_users=4" >> /system/build.prop
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Genymotion is a rooted device, an alternate approach would be to use
an app such as "4.2 Multiple User Enabler". This particular app is
available in the Play Store and is also open source:
https://github.com/SferaDev/4.2MultiuserEnabler.